# Die Übersetzung von "the Primary Health care center of the University"

Tags: translation, word-order

Die Ubersetzung von "the Primary Health care center of the University"

1-Das Zentrum für primäre Gesundheitsversorgung der Universität.

2-Das Zentrum der primären Gesundheitsversorgung der Universität.

Oder beide sind richtig?

Comment: Wofür das _primär_ steht weiß ich inhaltlich nicht, aber _das Primärgesundheitsversorgungszentrum der Universität_ wäre möglich. Oder geht es um gesundheitliche Erstversorgung?

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass die wörtliche Übersetzung im Kontext deutschsprachiger Institutionen nicht verwendet wird (siehe Antworten unten): syntaktisch "richtig" (= ususkonform) wäre "Zentrum **für** primäre Gesundheitsversorung". Mit "der" klingt es, als spräche jemand aus Russland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solange man nicht genau weiß, was das Zentrum alles bietet und wie groß das Gebäude ist, finde ich die Übersetzung als **"Zentrum für (die) medizinische Grundversorgung"** am besten. Erste Hilfe Station oder Krankenstation implizieren eine bestimmte Größe und Ausstattung.

Hauptproblem ist wie schon @ChristianGeiselmann in seinem Kommentar schreibt die fehlende direkte Entsprechung im deutschen. Da kommt es wohl auf den Kontext drauf an, was dieses Zentrum alles bietet. Benutzen sollte man bei der direkten Übersetzung aber eher **"Zentrum für"**.

Alternative Übersetzungen für den Begriff findest du unter https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/primary+health+care+center.html

Comment: Ich habe noch nicht verstanden, wieso **Zentrum für** besser als Irgendwas**station** sein soll, zumal **Zentrum** genauso sehr oder wenig eine bestimmte Größe und Ausstattung impliziert wie **Station**.

Answer (score 2):

Im Deutschen wäre das

> die [Krankenstation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krankenstation) der Universität.

Answer (score 2):

Um das richtige Wort zu finden, müsste man wissen, was so ein *primary health care center* konkret anbietet.

Wenn es um Dinge geht wie jemanden einen Verband anzulegen, der sich an einem zerbrochenen Erlenmeyerkolben geschnitten hat (oder was für Unfälle immer an der Uni vorkommen), oder jemandem, der mit Herzstillstand auf dem Boden liegend gefunden wurde, mit einem Defibrillator auf die Sprünge zu helfen bis der Notarzt kommt, dann sind neben der von anderen erwähnten *Krankenstation* auch

> Erste-Hilfe-Station

oder

> Erste-Hilfe-Stelle

gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary health care center** is a fixed phrase, which should to be translated as

> Gesundheitsstation

That's a place which has health care facilities of the *primary level*.

Es handelt sich also um die

> Gesundheitsstation der Universität

Comment: Du meinst sicherlich eine _Krankenstation_ (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krankenstation). Eine _Gesundheitsstation_ wäre ja das Gegenteil davon.

Comment: Ich meine auch, dass *Gesundheitsstation* in der Praxis nicht vorkommt. Es sei denn, irgend eine Universitätsverwaltung hätte, heimgesucht von einem Marketing-Berater, ihre Krankenstation oder Erste-Hilfe-Stelle weißwäscherisch umbenannt, so wie Krankenkassen ja auch (recht erfolglos) versuchen, sich als *Gesundheitskassen* zu verkaufen.

Comment: Ihr seid nicht mehr auf dem Laufenden: https://www.google.de/search?q=drk-gesundheitsstation